# getting value from column for each field, but it returns NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, mysqli

I am trying to get the value of "rounds" from the column rounds in my db. So, I want to get the value (1-5) of a field for each debate/post. Based on the value/number it is supposed to display a different thing. When I supposedly get the value It says NULL even though the value in the db field for that debate/post is 4. This is not just that debate, but this occurs for all of them. How can I get the actual value of the field in the column and assign it to a variable called $rounds . This variable needs to have the value for each debate made, not just that debate.

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else{
  $sql = "SELECT rounds FROM vf_Discussion";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    $allRounds = $result->fetch_row();
    $rounds = $allRounds[0];

    var_dump($rounds);   
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>

<?php    
      $rounds1 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Con) </h2>';
      $rounds2 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Con)</h2>';
      $rounds3 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Con)</h2>';
      $rounds4 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Con)</h2>';
      $rounds5 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Con)</h2>';
       ?>

<?php
    foreach($allRounds as $rounds) {
        if ($rounds == 1) {
            echo $rounds1;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 2) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 3) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 4) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }
        }
        if ($rounds == 5) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            echo $rounds5;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you tried : var_dump($allRounds); This will help you understand how to access results array (if any ).

Comment: `$allRounds` is just one row from the table, not all the rows.

Comment: No change in the result.

Comment: @Barmar , so then how do I get the result I want? Can you provide code? I want it to display the amount of rounds it says in the db for that debate/post. So, if the db value for that post is 4, I want it to display 4 rounds.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following and see if it gives you the desired result?
I have included prepared statements as opposed to your (unsafe) way of querying.

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";


$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT rounds FROM `vf_Discussion`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rounds);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {

        $rounds1 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 1 (Con) </h2>';

        $rounds2 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 2 (Con)</h2>';

        $rounds3 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 3 (Con)</h2>';

        $rounds4 =        '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 4 (Con)</h2>';

        $rounds5 =    '<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round 5 (Con)</h2>';

        if ($rounds == 1) {
            echo $rounds1;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }//end foreach
        }//end if
        if ($rounds == 2) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }//end foreach
        }//end if
        if ($rounds == 3) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }//end foreach
        }//end if
        if ($rounds == 4) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }//end foreach
        }//end if
        if ($rounds == 5) {
            echo $rounds1;
            echo $rounds2;
            echo $rounds3;
            echo $rounds4;
            echo $rounds5;
            foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
                $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
                WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
            }//end foreach
        }//end if

    }//end while
}//end else
?>
```

Comment: No, this just displays round 1 (pro) round 1 (con) round 2(pro) rounds 2( con) a lot of times and then eventually displays  rounds 3 (pro) etc. Not the result I needed.

Comment: In what variable is the field number stored for which you would like to retrieve the result?

Comment: I believe it is supposed to be stored in $rounds .

Comment: And what is the database column which stores the field number called?

Comment: It is called rounds .

Comment: Could you tell me exactly which columns are in the database table `vf_Discussion`?

Comment: all of them or certain ones/columns?

Comment: The ones that are related to the rounds, the field number and so forth

Comment: rounds is the only one related to it and is where the value is. Not sure of field number.

Comment: Can you provide code and/or a solution?

Comment: It is quite hard as your code indicates that rounds should be joined to a column with the field number which there is not. So all you can do is just provide a long list of rounds not bound to a certain field. You'll need to add a column to your database containing the field number for which there will be between 1 and 5 rounds.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you provide code or further instructions?

Comment: Add a column to the database `vf_Discussion` called FieldNumber and add the fields you have

Comment: what is the difference between that and my current rounds column?

Answer (score 0):

`$result->fetch_row()` just fetches one row of results. You have to call it in a loop to get all the rows.

And instead of all that duplicated code, use a loop to print the repeated `<h2>` elements, since they follow a simple pattern.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $round = $row['rounds'];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $round; $i++) {
        echo "<h2 class="CommentHeading">Round $i (Pro)</h2> <br> <h2 class="CommentHeading">Round $i (Con) </h2>";
    }
    foreach ($Sender->Data('Answers') as $Row) {
        $Sender->EventArguments['Comment'] = $Row;
        WriteComment($Row, $Sender, Gdn::Session(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes everything blank page, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is there an error in the server log?

Comment: No, just shows blank page.

Comment: If you put `echo` statements outside the loop, do you see them?